# Linux Server side php script for audio conversion like 32kbps,48kbps from one bitrate?

Tags: php, linux, audio, server

I want php script For audio conversion so , that i upload only one format it automatically converts into other formats

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow doesn't cater to "I want a script" questions that show no prior effort.  Stack Overflow isn't a "give me the codes" service.

Comment: i made the effort by using ffmpeg ... but i dont know how i used it in server

Comment: ffmpeg is good so is mplayer. go with the ones with the most docs and a low server resource based system. if you have a webpage where you're converting multiple audio files, it will hang and may crash the webserver from memory loss.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with php and you need an external program. Good thing its Linux, most audio conversion software is free because its open source.

```
//Include this in your php script to call it 
exec('sox /path/to/audio/files/audio_a.wav /path/to/audio/files/audio_a.mp3');
```

Make sure you install sox first on your machine and try it on the command line first and check the results and tweak with its arguments to fine tune the auto conversion then use php's exec function to process the entire file. The above example is basic. Here is a full argument list: http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html

Install it from: http://sox.sourceforge.net/
You can use git to pull the source.

Comment: i dont know how to install any program on server. i have just control panel

Comment: are you on shared host, virtual dedicated host? dedicated host? are you running cpanel? plesk? do you have number to call support or chat support if you don't have ssh access so you can have them install it?